# How to allow app to use Mobile Data in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm a beginner in iOS. I'm making an app that works both offline and online. On the default Settings app on iOS, my app has only access to Notifications and background App Refresh. How do I add the option to allow users to use mobile data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enabled by default - you don't have to do anything. The option will appear in the Settings page the first time you use mobile data with your app.

Answer (score 2):

When starting a basic project on Xcode your application by default is routed to work with cellular data. There is no need for any kind of external settings manipulation. If you really feel like configuring the overalls and the connection structures feel free to explore the " Networks " tab to better optimise your app.

And good luck with your new project !

Answer (score 0):

I just build an app in Xcode 14 and mobile data was off by default!